# jquery toggle_container using anchor links within a page to expand toggle

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, toggle, accordion

I am using a toggle container to expand sections of a large page. Within these section the content has links to not only other pages but to links in other sections of the page. I have tried to use anchor links and the page moves to the general area but will not expand the toggle.

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
  $(".toggle_container").hide();

  //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
  $("h3.trigger").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
  return true; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
  });
  $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent(".trigger").click();
  });
  if (window.location.hash) {
    $('h3.trigger + .toggle_container').hide(); // Hide all...
    $('h3.trigger').has("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").next('.toggle_container').show(); // ... but show one
    } 
</script>

<h3 class="trigger"><a name="1.8" href="#1.8">1.8 &nbsp;&nbsp; blah ablshdasd</a></h3>
<div class="toggle_container" >
   <p class="column1">1.8 &nbsp;&nbsp; djhsa;ksjag;fjgancvjwer design requirements.</p>
   <ol class="alpha-small">
      <li>more text</li>
   </ol>
   <br /><br />
<h3 class="trigger"><a  href="#1.9">1.9 &nbsp;&nbsp; Blah Blah</a></h3>
<div class="toggle_container">
   <p class="column1">text goes here...... <a href="#1.8">1.8.</a></p>            
   <br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: do you think you could make us a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7ztsG/7/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure window.location.hash works with jsfiddle...

I suspect if you were to change this line

```
$("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent(".trigger").click();
```

to use name= instead of href= it might do what you are expecting.

Alternatively, you could drop the reliance on the window.location.hash and do something more along the lines of this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrZbY/1/))

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
    $(".toggle_container").hide();

    //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
    $("h3.trigger").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
        return true; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });
    $("a.open").click(function() {
        hrefval = $(this).attr("href").match(/(\d+\.\d+)/)[1]
        $("a[name='" + hrefval + "']").parent(".trigger").click() //open the new one
    })
});
```

Note that this uses your class "open" to know what anchor tags to bind to for jumping within sections of the page.

Comment: This works great  for opening items within the page. But external links coming into the page  wont toggle open http://jsfiddle.net/allanblock/LweYZ/1/#&togetherjs=q7arG5ihUj